Outdated Responses in Dialogflow ES
I am currently using Dialogflow ES (free tier) for my conversational agent. After updating my backend logic and modifying the agent's responses, I still receive the previous responses during interactions.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Webhook Verification: Confirmed the webhook URL in the Fulfillment section points to the updated backend endpoint.
Deployment Confirmation: Ensured all backend changes are deployed and the server is running.
Webhook Activation: Checked that the relevant intents have the webhook option enabled.
Response Caching Issues: Attempted to refresh the cache by modifying intent settings.
Direct Testing of the Webhook: Used cURL and Postman to test the webhook endpoint directly.
Error Inspection: Reviewed the Diagnostic Info in the Dialogflow console for any errors.
Version Control Check: Verified I am testing the correct version of my agent.
Conflict Resolution: Checked for conflicting intents with overlapping training phrases.
Response Review: Examined the Response tab in the Dialogflow console during testing.
Retesting After Changes: Retested intents after making updates.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
